# Trouble with clearcase VOB database

Tags: hyperlink, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

I am getting the following error for most of the clearcase activities, like labeling, checkout etc.

```
cleartool: Error: Error from VOB database: "\11.3.0".
cleartool: Error: Trouble finding the global definition for local type "???".
cleartool: Error: Trouble applying label to
```

Some times it is going on, but most often failing with this error. Above is the error while applying a label. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Following the technote "[Fixing broken hyperlinks with Administrative VOBs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21231183)", check if you don't have a missing hyperlink between your vob and your admin vob (which, if you are using UCM, should be a PVob).

> An AdminVOB is a normal VOB that will be principally used to store globally defined metadata types (branch, label, attribute, elements and hyperlinks). See [here for more](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21148828).

Example of resolution (here in the case of a global type being a branch):

```
cleartool unlock vob:\ClientVOB
cleartool describe -long vob:\ClientVOB
 Hyperlinks:
   AdminVOB@53@\ClientVOB -> <object not available>
cleartool describe -local -long brtype:MyBranch@\ClientVOB
GlobalDefinition@54@\ClientVOB -> <object not available>
cleartool checkvob -hlink vob:\ClientVOB
cleartool describe -local -long brtype:MyBranch@\ClientVOB
cleartool checkvob -hlink brtype:MyBranch@\ClientVOB
cleartool mkhlink AdminVOB vob:\ClientVOB vob:\AdminVOB3
cleartool mkbrtype -global -acquire MyBranch@\AdminVOB3
```

> Doing all of this can be very lengthy in a case where numerous metadata types are broken, especially when it has to be done in all VOBs.
>   This could be scripted to automate the process.

---

Another cause: technote "[Deleted user accounts and ClearCase performance](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150848)":

> A user account that no longer exists, but is still listed in the -nusers option for cleartool lock of a branch can cause a checkout, checkin and merge to fail like:

So if you have a lock on a branch, that can also be an issue.